# Plotting $l^p$ circles

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a couple of $l^p$ circles, but when $p=\infty$ its not quite showing up (the max one in the code below):

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^4 + y^4 == 1, 
  Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Is there a way to plot this (preferably not telling *Mathematica* that it's a square)?

Comment: For searching purposes: these are also termed Lamé curves or superellipses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get sampling points on both sides of the curve for it to show up with `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^4 + y^4 == 1, 
  Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1}, {x, -1.05, 1.05}, {y, -1.05, 1.05}(*, Exclusions -> None*)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add the option `Exclusions -> None` to remove the gaps in the corners.  *Mathematica* is thinking there is a discontinuity, but it's wrong.

**Addendum**

With a little trickery, you can use `Norm[v, p]` and make a slider run between `Infinity` and `1`:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Norm[{x, y}, Limit[1/pp, pp -> p]], {x, -1.05, 1.05}, {y, -1.05, 1.05}],
 Row[{Control[{p, 0, 1}], 
   InputField[Dynamic[Limit[1/pp, pp -> p], If[# >= 1, p = 1/#] &], 
    Appearance -> "Frameless"]}, " "]
 ]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note for the `Manipulate`: To enter infinity, enter `Infinity`, not `\[Infinity]` or `ESC` `inf` `ESC`.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125825/inputfield-does-not-accept-all-single-character-expressions.

Answer (score 5):

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[Norm[{x, y}, #] <= 1 & /@ {1, 2, 4, Infinity}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add the option `PlotStyle -> {None, None, None, None}]` to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]