# InputField does not accept all single-character expressions

Tags: gui-construction, inputfield

When I enter <kbd>ESC</kbd>`inf`<kbd>ESC</kbd> or `\[Infinity]` into an `InputField`, such as that below, the input is rejected when I hit tab or return.

```
Dynamic@foo
InputField[Dynamic@foo]
```

The same thing happens if I enter Greek characters, such as <kbd>ESC</kbd>`e`<kbd>ESC</kbd> or `\[Epsilon]`.

However if I enter `1 + \[Infinity]` it is accepted, evaluates to `Infinity`, and is displayed as `∞`.  Odd that `∞` is supported as output but not input.  Also entering `Infinity` works.  Likewise, `0 + \[Epsilon]` is accepted and evaluates to `ϵ`. The input `\[Epsilon]\[Epsilon]` is also accepted.

No doubt it happens for other characters such as <kbd>ESC</kbd>`ee`<kbd>ESC</kbd>, although `E` is accepted.  Again, if <kbd>ESC</kbd>`ee`<kbd>ESC</kbd> is part of a longer expression, it works fine.

Is this a known limitation? I did not find it in the documentation.  Or is it a bug?

Note: This seems to be a problem on V11.0.0 and V10.4.1 (and perhaps earlier).  Mac OSX 10.11.6, MacBook Pro.

Comment: Must be OS dependent? I can enter esc e esc and other Greek letters, as well as Infinity, esc inf esc, and \[Infinity] and they all seem OK. Mac OS 10.11 V 11.0.0

Comment: Appears to work fine on Win7 V11.0.0

Comment: @bills I'm on MacOSX 10.11.6, MacBook Pro, V11.0.0.  The problem persists after rebooting the computer.

Comment: I can replicate this weird behavior (Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on OS X 10.11.6)

Comment: If no one can reproduce the problem, I guess I'll delete the question after a while.  This works fine for me: `InputField[Dynamic@foo, Hold[Expression]]` (probably not important).

Comment: Thanks @Sascha. I think I'll report it to WRI. I hope the developer who reviews it can reproduce it also.